# Drop Down Box not working in JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, drop-down-menu

Making a drop down list for my JSP and the values I'm entering won't show. Probably me being an idiot but a solution would be really helpful

**The drop down box appears but the values to select are empty.**

It's a big JSP so here's the piece that I'm looking at..

Form is put at the top of the JSP:

```
out.println("<form action=\"ExchangeServlet\" method=\"get\">");
```

At the bottom of the jsp:

```
out.println("<select name =\"status\">"+
"option value =\"Accepted\">Accepted</option>"+
"option value =\"Declined\">Declined</option>"+
"</select>");
out.println("<br />");
out.println("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Update Exchange\" />");
out.println("</form>");
```

Comment: Perhaps using valid HTML for those options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid.

Change

```
out.println("<select name =\"status\">"+
"option value =\"Accepted\">Accepted</option>"+
"option value =\"Declined\">Declined</option>"+
"</select>");
```

to

```
out.println("<select name =\"status\">"+
"<option value =\"Accepted\">Accepted</option>"+
"<option value =\"Declined\">Declined</option>"+
"</select>");
```

Comment: @Jimmy, definitely happens to all of us!